# ajax request with form_remote_tag doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I'm using a form_remote_tag to attempt an ajax form submission, like so:

```
<% form_remote_tag :update=> 'test', :url=> {:action=>'test_action'} do -%>
```

It renders with no apparent problem:

```
<form action="/pages/test_action" method="post" onsubmit="new Ajax.Updater('test', '/pages/test_action', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;">
```

The test_action action:

```
def test_action
  if request.xhr?
    render :text => 'some text'
  else
    puts 'nope'
  end
end
```

When I submit the form(via the submit button, nothing weird like the jquery submit() event), no ajax request is made. The xhr check returns false. Help please??

Answer (score 0):

In controller you should respond to specified format, js in your case. For example:

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params[:item])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Item was successfully created.'
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to(@item) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @item, :status => :created, :location => @item }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @item.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The best practice for now is to use [unobtrusive javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) (UJS). There is no `form_remote_tag` in rails 3. UJS can be used [with rails 2.3 as well](http://andrewcox.org/post/507032751/rails-3-0-unobtrusive-ajax-in-rails-2-3-x).

Comment: shouldn't request.xhr? at least return true though? that action was just something i was using to test to see if the ajax request was being sent.